# Can a non-Elven drinker benefit from an Elven Alchemist Blend spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alchemist

If an Elven alchemist with the [Infusion](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo-alchemist-discoveries/infusion) discovery creates an extract of the [Blend](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blend/) spell, would that work on a non-Elven drinker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes

Blend references "draw[ing] upon your elven link to the wilderness" but has no *requirement* nor *restriction* that you must be an Elf. There is no portion of the spell that you must be an Elf or that non-Elves cannot benefit from it. In fact, as written, even a non-Elf alchemist, druid, magus, psychic, ranger, shaman, sorcerer/wizard, or witch could prepare Blend if taught how by an Elf. In cases where this is not true, the rules [say so explicitly](https://aonprd.com/Spells.aspx)

> Spell requires a requisite religion or race. If religion, spellcaster must worship the listed deity to utilize the spell. If race, the spell might only target members of the listed race **(the spell will say this if it does)**, but often are just the race's guarded secrets. Members of other races can learn to cast them with GM permission.